# How to send multiple files FormData where each file belong to a different FormControl?

Tags: javascript, angular, multipartform-data, angular-forms

I'm building a website where a teacher can upload their own course.

**Course Structure**

```
CourseName
|-Module1
  |-Lecture 1
  |-Lecture 2
|-Module2
  |-Lecture 1
  |-Lecture 2
```

**The form values structure looks something like**

```
{
  "coursename": "Complete java beginners guide",
  "board": 0,
  "class": 3,
  "coursedescription": "Learn java from scratch",
  "modules": [
    {
      "modulename": "Week 1: Intro to java",
      "lectures": [
        {
          "lecturename": "Data types in Java",
          "lecturepath": {
            "0": {}
          },
          "lecturedescription": "learn datatypes in java"
        },
        {
          "lecturename": "Primary vs Secondary types",
          "lecturepath": {
            "0": {}
          },
          "lecturedescription": "learn about primary vs secondary type"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "modulename": "Week 2 some more learning",
      "lectures": [
        {
          "lecturename": "module 2 lecture 1",
          "lecturepath": {
            "0": {}
          },
          "lecturedescription": "learn this lecture"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

where **lecturepath** holds the file.

I can't figure out how to configure the FormData to send it back to the server.

So far I have this but this, of course, isn't working

```
onSubmitNewCourse() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('course', this.form.value);
    TODO:handle files
  }
```

Help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Does your form tag have the following attribute: `enctype='multipart/form-data'`?

Comment: @andriusain Yes, it does

Comment: so if you are handling the submission entirely with JavaScript rather than a standard form submit request then you need to handle those file uploads with Javascript as well, and send the file data manually via XHR to a server script to save the file

Comment: I'm using Angular for this and would like an Angular based solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your file is rightly append to the formData as Blob or Binary?

For an angular solution I don't know what your application looks like but I proposed you to create a formGroup for all your data and maybe create a service to upload your file into the right course module via the formData like your above code with the file in blob